# Otto: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: start [class android.app.Activity]"

Tags: android, otto

On some of the devices I'm getting this error when trying to send an event with the Otto event bus:

**Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event: class xxx.xxx.MyEvent to handler [EventHandler public void xxx.xxx.onEventReceived(xxx.xxx.MyEvent)]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: start [class android.app.Activity]**

What is **start [class android.app.Activity]** and why am I getting this exception?

I've tried to reproduce with some other devices and I can not. Seemingly this only happens on some devices, randomly. It might be related to Proguard, since I'm getting this from the obfuscated app. It's a multidex app if that's of any help

Comment: Might be a lower API version on the device?

Comment: When dispatching to `onEventReceived(MyEvent)` your method tried to call a `start(Activity)` method but failed because there is no such method. Might be proguard. Should there be such a method? `start [class android.app.Activity]` = `start(Activity param)`, I guess it's in the same class as your event handler. See somewhat self-explaining stacktrace in http://stackoverflow.com/q/11695835

Comment: @Murat K, no it works on the same API level for me

Comment: @zapl No, I do not have any such start() method, neither Activity has as I can see from the Activity.java AOSP file. Only my method is annotated by Subscribe annotation but somehow Otto complains about start()

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken and edited my comment, it's not a method of activity, it's a method that has an activity as it's only parameter. Do you get a stacktrace with a `caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` section? It should contain the place that tries to call that method as it's first entry.

Comment: Look here https://github.com/square/otto/issues/37, probably you are having the same issue